# while sending array from android to server 1st element sets at server side 0 value but in android it sets correct value what is the solution

Tags: android

[server data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbRQV.jpg)

[android data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8s3d.jpg)

I am passing arraylist of srid of all element and post to server using volley request.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLPle.png)

here is the code

```
public class AttendenceShowStdList extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityAttendenceShowStdListBinding AttendenceShowStdList;

    ArrayList<AttStdListModel> userlist = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<AllStdListsrIdAdmIdModel> list= new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<AllStdListModel> stdlist = new ArrayList<>();

    AttStdListAdapter adapter;
    private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    private String date,clid,sectionId,yrId,instId,usid,usType,attdate;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences_teach;//staff shareprefferece for profile fetch

    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME_TEACH="myprefteach";
    private static final String Key_USID_TEACH = "techusid";
    private static final String Key_INSTID_TEACH = "techinstid";
    private static final String Key_USTYPE_TEACH = "techustype";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AttendenceShowStdList= ActivityAttendenceShowStdListBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(AttendenceShowStdList.getRoot());

        sharedPreferences_teach =getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME_TEACH, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        instId=sharedPreferences_teach.getString(Key_INSTID_TEACH,null);
        usid=sharedPreferences_teach.getString(Key_USID_TEACH,null);
        usType=sharedPreferences_teach.getString(Key_USTYPE_TEACH,null);

        //getting data from TakeAttendenceAdapter cardview
        clid=getIntent().getExtras().getString("ClassId");
        sectionId=getIntent().getExtras().getString("sectionId");
        Log.d("cliddd",clid);
        yrId=getIntent().getExtras().getString("YearId");


        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        date = sdf.format(new Date());
        Log.d("dttt",date);


        userlist = (ArrayList<AttStdListModel>) getModel(false);
        adapter = new AttStdListAdapter(this,userlist);
        AttendenceShowStdList.rvstdlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        AttendenceShowStdList.rvstdlist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

//        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
//        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        getData();


        //toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(AttendenceShowStdList.toolbar);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        AttendenceShowStdList.submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                submitAttendence();

//                Intent intent = new Intent(AttendenceShowStdList.this,SubmitAttendenceActivity.class);
//                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }
    private List<AttStdListModel> getModel(boolean isSelect){
        List<AttStdListModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){

            AttStdListModel model = new AttStdListModel();
            model.setSelected(isSelect);
//            model.setStud_name(String.valueOf(list.get(i)));
            model.setAdmi_id(String.valueOf(list.get(i)));
            list.add(model);
        }
        return list;
    }


    private void getData() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        String url1="https://comzent.in/wonderschoolerp/apis/teacher/get_studteachers_att.php";


        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url1, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                //  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Data added to API", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {

                    JSONObject respObj = new JSONObject(response);

                    JSONArray jsonArray5=respObj.getJSONArray("studatt_details");

                    Log.d("std details",jsonArray5.toString());
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray5.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray5.getJSONObject(i);
                        String sr_id=jsonObject.optString("sr_id");
                        String admi_id=jsonObject.optString("admi_id");
                        String stud_name=jsonObject.optString("stud_name");
                        String stud_phone=jsonObject.optString("stud_phone");
                        String stud_email=jsonObject.optString("stud_email");
                        String attd_status=jsonObject.optString("attd_status");
                        String attd_reason=jsonObject.optString("attd_reason");

                        userlist.add(new AttStdListModel(sr_id,admi_id,stud_name,stud_phone,stud_email,
                                attd_status,attd_reason));
                        Log.d("s", String.valueOf(userlist));
                        list.add(new AllStdListsrIdAdmIdModel(sr_id,admi_id,stud_name,stud_phone,stud_email,
                                attd_status,attd_reason));

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                adapter=new AttStdListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),userlist);
                AttendenceShowStdList.rvstdlist.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail to get response = " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


                params.put("get_studattd","1");
                params.put("us_id",usid);
                params.put("inst_id",instId);
                params.put("class_id",clid);
                params.put("sec_id",sectionId);
                params.put("ay_id",yrId);
                params.put("stud_attend_date",date);


                return params;
            }
        };

        queue.add(request);
    }

    //submit attendence

    private void submitAttendence() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        String url1="https://comzent.in/wonderschoolerp/apis/teacher/take_studteacher_att.php";


        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url1, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                //  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Data added to API", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {

                    JSONObject respObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    String msg=respObj.getString("message");
                    Toast.makeText(AttendenceShowStdList.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("response msg",msg);
                    if(msg.equals("Attendance Generated Successfully..!")){
                        finish();


                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail to get response = " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("error msg", String.valueOf(error));

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                ArrayList<String> allstdsrid = new ArrayList<String>();

                for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                    allstdsrid.add(String.valueOf(list.get(i).getSr_id()));

                }
                params.put("sr_id", String.valueOf(allstdsrid));
                Log.d("params", String.valueOf(params));

                Log.d("allstudentsrid", String.valueOf(allstdsrid));

                ArrayList<String> allstdadmid = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                        allstdadmid.add(list.get(i).getAdmi_id());
                        params.put("admission_id", String.valueOf(allstdadmid));
                }
                Log.d("allstudentsadmid", String.valueOf(allstdadmid));

                ///selected student list
                ArrayList<String> attstd = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < AttStdListAdapter.userlist.size(); i++) {
                    if (AttStdListAdapter.userlist.get(i).getSelected()) {
                        attstd.add(AttStdListAdapter.userlist.get(i).getAdmi_id());
                    }
                }

                params.put("student_attend_submit","1");
                params.put("class_id",clid);
                params.put("sec_id",sectionId);
                params.put("ay_id",yrId);
                params.put("att_status", String.valueOf(attstd));
                Log.d("params", String.valueOf(params));
                params.put("stud_attend_date",date);
                params.put("inst_id",instId);
                params.put("us_id",usid);
                params.put("us_type",usType);

                return params;
            }
        };

        queue.add(request);
    }


    //toolbar back to home
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){

            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

After  submitting attendance, values of array of srid and admid retrive at server correctly ,problem is that only first record's srid and admid sets to '0' value.There is no problem when same Api is fetch on postman.

Comment: Well this is a super example of how not to post. Please dont change anything for further reference ;-)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.